# Spring MVC Form Hibernate Validator : Cross parameter constraint has no cross parameter validator

Tags: forms, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Here is my Form

```
public class TaskForm extends WebForm<TaskModel> {

    public TaskForm(){
        this(new TaskModel());
    }

    public TaskForm(TaskModel form) {
        super(form);
    }


    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    public void setName(String taskName){
        target.setTaskName(taskName);
    }


    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    public void setDescription(String description){
        target.setDescription(description);
    }

    public void setStartDate(DateTime startDate){
        target.setStartDate(startDate);
    }

    public DateTime getStartDate(){
        return target.getStartDate();
    }

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    public void setEndDate(DateTime endDate){
        target.setEndDate(endDate);
    }

    public DateTime getEndDate(){
        return target.getEndDate();
    }

    public String getName(){
        return target.getTaskName();
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return target.getDescription();
    }
}
```

When I submitted the form it threw me an Exception.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintDefinitionException: HV000154: Cross parameter constraint org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty has no cross-parameter validator.
```

What caused this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your @NotNull and @NotEmpty validation constraint in the getter. Change your form like this

```
public class TaskForm extends WebForm<TaskModel> {

    public TaskForm(){
        this(new TaskModel());
    }

    public TaskForm(TaskModel form) {
        super(form);
    }

    public void setName(String taskName){
        target.setTaskName(taskName);
    }



    public void setDescription(String description){
        target.setDescription(description);
    }

    public void setStartDate(DateTime startDate){
        target.setStartDate(startDate);
    }

    public DateTime getStartDate(){
        return target.getStartDate();
    }

    //@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    public void setEndDate(DateTime endDate){
        target.setEndDate(endDate);
    }

    public DateTime getEndDate(){
        return target.getEndDate();
    }

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    public String getName(){
        return target.getTaskName();
    }

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    public String getDescription(){
        return target.getDescription();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bean constraints must be on the fields or getters of a type. If you place them on setters which return void, the validation engine assumes a cross parameters constraint (method validation). Moving the constraints will fix the problem.

Comment: I was thinking that the Validation Engine is expecting a return value from the method where the constraint is placed, in his case, he placed it at void method and that's also one of the reason why it threw an exception.

Comment: For method validation a constraint on a non getter method can either be a return value constraint or what is called a cross parameter constraint which can be used to validate all method parameters and their relation to each other. Since the methods in the example were returning void, the validation engine assumes a cross parameter constraint and tries to find a matching constraint validator which it cannot find. Hence the error.

Comment: any documentation for that? I have not seen that description or regulation on the validation constraint

Comment: Sure, check the Bean Validation specification http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints. Mind you that this is Bean Validation 1.1. Bean Validation 1.0 did not specify method validation. There the constraint would have just been ignored.